# ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ‪ (U+202A) when using crossref

Tags: biblatex, cross-referencing

I'm trying to cite this reference, but whenever I compile it with pdflatex, biblatex and biber, I get the error "! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ‪ (U+202A)". I already checked my files for special characters, but I think I isolated it to just the reference. Other examples from biblatex work fine with the crossref. When I comment out the crossref, I can compile it, but the bibliography does not include the proceedings. Any guesses why this strange error occurs?

```
@proceedings{UCAMI2018,
  title        = {The 12\textsuperscript{th} International Conference on Ubiquitous Computing and Ambient ‪Intelligence (UCAmI 2018)},
  location     = {Punta Cana, Dominican Republic},
  series       = {19},
  volume       = {2},
  publisher    = {MDPI},
  year         = 2018,
  month        = dec
}

@inproceedings{Espinilla2018,
  crossref    = {UCAMI2018},
  author      = {Macarena Espinilla and Javier Medina and Chris Nugent},
  title       = {UCAmI Cup. Analyzing the UJA Human Activity Recognition Dataset of Activities of Daily Living},
  doi    = {10.3390/proceedings2191267},

}
```

Comment: There is an invisible `U+202a LEFT-TO-RIGHT EMBEDDING` symbol at the space between `Ambient ‪Intelligence`. Just delete that but of the reference and retype it. (If you move your cursor to before the `I` in `Intelligence` you will find that you have to hit backspace twice to remove the space: Once for the invisible character and once for the actual space.)

Comment: Just a remark: in the [cover of the proceedings volume](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qais.png), we read “The 12th International Conference…” and “th” is not superscripted.